# Ecommerce - live search, select, and bill

Tags: javascript, html, php, mysql, jquery

I need a php/mysql plugin for server side, and js/jquery / or what so ever for client side.

My problem is:
- users search product in the search bar
- beneth the search box, the products will display with the checkbox facility and this is the result of search (AJAX)

(Note : The products can display in a tabular format with certain columns like name, price, category from database, and quantities, total price, checkbox to select/deselet or add/delete from list in realtime using jquery/js or other)

the checked products do not go away even when the searched content changes.

I have seen exactly same plugin couple of months ago that was using jquery. when i need it, i am not able to find it. please recommend me some plugins.

I am not looking for ecommerce applications like prestashop,shopify,magento,drupal or others even though some of their features match with this. i am fairly looking for plugin that i can use for my code.

thank you in advance.